# show $(\dfrac{y+1}{y-1})^b \gt \dfrac{y+b}{y-b}$ where $y \gt 1 \gt b \gt 0$

Tags: inequality

I am having difficulty showing (1): $\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)^b \gt \frac{y+b}{y-b}$ where (2): $y \gt 1 \gt b \gt 0$

If I let (3): $b=0$ or (4): $b=1$, I get (5): $\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)^b = \frac{y+b}{y-b}$

When I looked at it numerically, (1) seems to be true given (2), but I don't think I have the techniques to show this. I've just gone in circles. And I've done some things I'm not sure make sense (ie. from (1), do LHS less RHS, and get the slopes at $b=0$ (decreasing) and $b=1$ (increasing), but I haven't shown that there aren't any zeros in between (I know there aren't, but I can't show it).

Could I maybe do a Taylor series expansion around b, and compare them?

I have no real math background, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define $q = y/b$, which gives $q>y>1$ and the inequality becomes
$(\dfrac{y+1}{y-1})^{y/q} \gt \dfrac{y+y/q}{y-y/q}$

or $ \qquad (\dfrac{q-1}{q+1})^q \gt (\dfrac{y-1}{y+1})^{y} $. So we need to prove that the function $f(x) = (\dfrac{x-1}{x+1})^x $ is increasing with $x$ for $x > 1$. Let us equivalently regard $g(x) = \log f(x) = x \log (x-1) - x \log (x+1)$ and prove that  $g(x)$ is increasing with $x$. For this, $h(x) = g'(x) =  \log(\dfrac{x-1}{x+1})  + 2x/(x^2- 1)$ must be positive   for $x > 1$. We have $h'(x) = -4/(x^2 - 1)^2$ so for $x >1$, $h'(x) < 0$ and $h(x)$ is falling everywhere. Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = 0$, we have that   $h(x) $ is indeed positive, which proves the claim. $\qquad \Box$